# Weird behavior of IReadonlySessionState

Tags: asp.net, session

I don't know how (and this is what I want to know).

I have an HttpHandler which implements IReadonlySessionState marker interface. My idea was not to update the Session variables in the handler. But we accidentally call code which is saving data in a session and somehow the session is saving data.

Then we moved our project to Azure and decided to use Azure Cache. Because of the change of SessionStateProvider, now the session is not saving the data (and it should not because the handler is readonly).

I want to know if there is any bug in default session provider which is causing the session to be persisted even when manipulated in Readonly Http Handler.

Answer (score 0):

`IReadOnlySessionState` tells the session state provider that this handler doesn't need to save session state.
The handler is not obligated to refuse to save anything.

The default handler doesn't have any reason to not save session state (since it's in-process), so it always saves.

Comment: thanx for such a quick response. Do u mean default sessionstate provider always saves the session no matter in what mode u want to load. and "Microsoft.Web.DistributedCache.DistributedCacheSessionStateStoreProvider" this provider takes care of the marker interfaces implemented by the http handler.